# How to create an email based on a template?

Tags: excel, vba, templates, outlook

I tried setting up an email as a function but I hit the maximum number of carriage returns.

I would like to make the email a template so that it is easier to update then send.

What I have works for shorter messages. My message is long so I think that a template will be best.

```vb
Sub Sample_Auto_Generated_Email()
    Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
    Email_Cc, Email_Body As String
    Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
    
    Email_Subject = "Sample MAR Email"
    
    Email_Send_From = "Richard.Sabbara@x.com"
    
    Email_Send_To = "Richard.Sabbara@x.com"
    Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    objMailItem.Display
    strEmailAddr = "Richard.Sabbara@x.com"
    objMailItem.Recipients.Add strEmailAddr
    objMailItem.Subject = "Sample"
    objMailItem.Body = GetMessageBody()  
    objMailItem.Send
    Set objMailItem = Nothing
    Set objOutl = Nothing
End Sub


' This Function has been added.
Function GetMessageBody() As String
    GetMessageBody = "Good Afternoon" & vbNewLine & _
        Chr(10) & _
        "Attached is your Monthly Action Report (MAR) for May 2018." & vbNewLine & _
        Chr(10) & _
        "This report has been password protected with your practice password provided         
        to you by your ACOP Care Coordinator in April 2018." & vbNewLine & _
        Chr(10) & _
        "Technical questions (such as, how to access the MAR, password issues, not 
        receiving the email, etc.), please contact the Physician Engagement team at 
        providerservices@ax.com."
        Chr (10) & _
        "Questions related to the patient data contained within the MAR, please `enter code here`
        contact your ACO Partner Care Coordinator."
        Chr (10) & _
        "Thank you,"
End Function
```

Comment: The code works, I want it to send an email template and not an embedded message.  If my template is called temp.oft I wang it to open that for the message.

Comment: I have found the following code and it opens the template, I just need to add a to, from, cc, subject line and attachment.            
 Sub OutlookTemplate1()

Dim myolapp As Object
Dim myitem As Object

Set myolapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
myolapp.Session.Logon
'Modify the link and title of the file to work with your example
Set myitem = myolapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\e4h7x8r\Desktop\Test_Templates.oft")
myitem.Display 'or send
End Sub

Comment: You should not use a function here

Comment: You might just want to use the built-in [template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-an-email-message-based-on-a-template-56c645fc-1b25-4059-808b-55ee72b6bc2d) and use vba to kick it off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a document the suffix named .docx, put you template in this document.

Replace your code to the below code:

```
Sub Sample_Auto_Generated_Email()
Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
Email_Cc, Email_Body As String
Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim oMail As MailItem

    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set doc = wd.documents.Open("D:\aa.docx")
    doc.Content.Copy
    doc.Close
    Set wd = Nothing
    Email_Subject = "Sample MAR Email"

    Email_Send_From = “"

    Email_Send_To = ""
    Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    objMailItem.Display
    strEmailAddr = ""
    objMailItem.Recipients.Add strEmailAddr
    objMailItem.Subject = "Sample"
    objMailItem.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
    Set editor = objMailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor
        editor.Content.Paste
    'objMailItem.HTMLBody =
    objMailItem.Send
    Set objMailItem = Nothing
    Set objOutl = Nothing

    End Sub
```

This is my result:

[image]

Comment: I agree that an approach with some external place to store the message makes more sense

Comment: I got the following to work by creating small sets of the text in each function. 
 it might not be the cleanest but it work.  Thank you.Sub Sample_Auto_Generated_Email_Final()

Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
            .Subject = "MAR Report"
            .To = "Richard.Sabbara@x.com"
            .Body = GetMessageBody() & GetMessageBody2()
            .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\e4h7x8r\Desktop\History.txt"
            .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\e4h7x8r\Desktop\Dr. C Report.xlsx"
            .Send
    End With

End Sub